# React listen if page is running on port

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Hi I want show another webpage in a react-iframe.

This page is delivered by a server running on another port in localhost.

Is there a way that react can check if the page is running (Like listening if something is running on the port), to display it then in the iFrame?

Comment: try to read some [static] data (json file, jpg, index, whatever)

Comment: @xadm how can I do this so I got notified when reading this works

Comment: any error handling - f.e. try cach

Comment: @xadm but would you propose to read all the time till I succeed or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: just use some flag in the state - use `setState` for cases when it should or not render iframe

Comment: @xadm my issue is that I not know when the server is running that provides the site. But I want to be notified when it is by observing the port or the file. I don’t know how to try to access the file all the time

Comment: use intervals ?